# CMake - cannot build OpenCascade from source

Tags: cmake, build, mingw, mingw-w64, opencascade

I am trying to Build OpenCascade from source.
I am using this guide:
https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/blob/master/BUILD.MINGWw64.md

All the steps from 1-5, which include downloading stuff have been performed.
Now i am trying to build using CMAKE

*I used "Where is the source code" option to point to the directory of the oce (as instructed).
*I used "Where to build the binaries" option, to point the a folder which i named 'BUILD' inside the directory mentioned in the above step (as instructed).
*I pressed 'Configure' and selected "MSYS Makefiles" with default native compilers.

Here started the errors.
I noticed that CMake had produced a text file, so i went inside and changed the CMAKE MAKE location: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin

There i moved forward but new errors spawned.

so how do i move forward?

The guide then says:
"
Check OCE_USE_BUNDLE_SOURCE
Check OCE_WITH_FREEIMAGE
Check OCE_WITH_GL2PS
Check OCE_VISUALISATION
"

Where do i set these?
There are no such variables inside the text file, and neither i can set them up on CMAKE.

EDIT:
These are the errors i get now:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_a5bfb/fast && 
Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_d3ad7/fast && 
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_d3ad7/fast && Access is denied
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_d3ad7/fast && 
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

EDIT 2:
There are some null options in CMake:

[image]

EDIT 3:
After following the advice of Tsyvarev, i changed the line to

```
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin/make.exe
```

These are the errors i get:

```
 The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
    The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
    Detecting C compiler ABI info
    CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_51dc6/fast && 
    Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
    Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
    CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_88ba8/fast && 
    Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
      The C compiler
    
        "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
    
      is not able to compile a simple test program.
    
      It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_88ba8/fast && Access is denied
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin cmTC_88ba8/fast && 
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: "Here started the errors." - Which **exact** errors? Currently you question is read like "I got *some* errors, could you help me?".

Comment: It cuoldnt find the make executable but i solved it with that entry on the text file. The new errors are edited in the question now.

Comment: You are trying to build the Community Edition of Open CASCADE. This is a very old version of Open CASCADE and it has not changed for quite a long time. Why not use the official version https://dev.opencascade.org/?

Comment: Your make command looks weird. How did you use CMake? Did you enter the commands yourself? You could for example ensure that your compiler is within the path, run `cmake-gui`, choose a new build directory, select the source directory and then run `Configure`. Then CMake tries to find all configurations and commands on its own and just tells you (by marking the entries red) what it needs additionally and hasn't found yet.

Comment: "It couldn't find the make executable but I solved it with that entry on the text file." - 1. You solved it **wrong**: Variable `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` should contain the path to the **executable**, but you assign a **directory** (`C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin`) to it. 2. CMake normally is able to find a make executable by itself. Inability to doing this usually signals about wrong [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) selected or wrong environment settings. BTW, what *CMake generator* have you selected?

Comment: Also, please add to the question post the **exact error messsage** when CMake cannot find a make executable.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler The onyl reason i want to have openCascade, is because i want to compile this program: https://github.com/chfritz/step2stl. It says it needs OpenCascade. I didn't know there was a windows executable. So that's why i was trying to build the source. However, the download page required login before downloading. Is this normal? I thought it was open source. As for your second comment, i didn't understand it. I didn't run any commands. I was just following this guide: https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/blob/master/BUILD.MINGWw64.md. Will dling the exe help me compile that program?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I edited the question.

Comment: @user1584421 Yes, it's open source, but they want you to login before downloading it. It seems that step2stl has been programmed for Open CASCADE 6.5. In this case actually the older community edition might be suited well enough?! If the entries like `OCE_USE_BUNDLE_SOURCE` did not appear, then probably you have chosen the wrong source folder. In the OCE source folder there must be a file named `CMakeLists.txt`. This is the right folder! Choose this one and press `Configure` again.

Comment: Also Oce-Win-Bundle has changed, but they have not updated the documentation. Now it must be cloned into the OCE-directory for automatic configuration to succeed. So if your OCE repository has been cloned to a directory `oce`, there must be a file `oce/CMakeLists.txt`, a subdirectory `oce/oce-win-bundle` and a file `oce/oce-win-bundle/CMakeLists.txt`. Then you have set up your project the right way and can start with the configuration and compilation steps.

Comment: Not sure where you have changed `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`, but according to the output, CMake still uses `C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeas you were right, i messed up. I fixed it now.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Thanks a lot! You were very helpful, i am almost there!. However now, in the documentatiton it says "Select the directory of your oce-win-bundle clone with OCE_BUNDLE_ROOT_PATH". However there is no option on CMake. Is it because i have placed the oce-win-bundle inside the oce folder?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I have finished with CMake. It successfully generated the build files. So i go to do the next step in the documentation, 'Run MSYS and make'. However, i start  msys.bat in the msys directory - separate from oce directory and i run it as Administrator. I get his message inside the command prompt "The system cannot find the path specified". At the same time an alert pops up that displays the message "Windows cannot find C:\Users\User1\Desktop\OpenCascade. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again". However, i didn't type any name, i just run the bat like the docs

Comment: I use MSYS2, therefore I am not sure... is there also a `msys.exe`, that you could start? Isn't there also an entry in the Windows start menu to open a MSYS shell? If it fails completely, you could also try MSYS2 (I have switched several year ago). Good luck!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I did that. I got msys2. I am unsure if there is conflict with the old msys, because in the CMake configuration, i pointed 
'CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin/make.exe' (inside CMakeCache.txt) and this is the old version of msys that i had.
Anyway i started msys 2, edited 'etc/nsswitch.conf' with: 'db_home: windows' and cd'd into the BUILD directory, where CMake was generating all the files.
Typed 'make' into msys2 shell, just like the documentation says and i got 'bash: make: command not found'.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Could you please offer some insights? I am documenting all the process, so other users can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: Most probably `make` is in your Windows path, but MSYS2 does not necessarily add the Windows path to its own path. If you check the file `msys2.ini` in your MSYS2 installation folder, you can add (or uncomment?) the line `MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit`, then all executables in your Windows path should be available within MSYS2 without definiting your MSYS2 path manually.

Comment: Another remark: if you use mingw-w64 and you do parallel builds and there are strange build errors, you might want to try the make executable named `mingw32-make`. With it, parallel builds work great here. So if (hopefully soon) the build works, you might want to do `mingw32-make -j 16` to start up to sixteen compiler instances for quick parallel builds.

Comment: @user1584421 "download page required login before downloading. Is this normal? I thought it was open source" - OCCT source code is available without login, just not well-documented yet: https://dev.opencascade.org/index.php?q=node/1212#comment-864

Comment: I typed make in the command line and the program is not recognized there as well. The only make.exe i have is the one on the msys directory (the old one - the one the original documentation told me to get but didn't start.). I did a system scan and i found it only there. But i have MinGW, msys2 isntalled. How come i don't have make?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler i installed make using 'pacman -S --needed base-devel'. I head to the build location, type make and i get these errors:

Comment: @BenjaminBihler $ make
Scanning dependencies of target freetype
[  0%] Building C object oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/src/autofit/autofit.c.obj
make[2]: *** [oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/build.make:83: oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/src/autofit/autofit.c.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2540: oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2

Comment: But then the comment of user Tsyvarev comes into play: which CMake generator have you selected? In `cmake-gui` you will find its name next to the three buttons `Configure`, `Generate`, `Open Project`. With your configuration you should probably use "MSYS Makefiles" or perhaps "MinGW Makefiles" as generator. Before changing the generator you might have to delete your build directory and restart the configuration?

Comment: It says: Current Generator: MSYS Makefiles. I followed the instruction fro mthe documentation.

Comment: But i have to add that in that process, i had the 'old' msys. not the msys2 that i actually typed 'make'

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I deleted the Build and started all over again. I choose the two directories. I set the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to /bin/make.exe (OF THE MSYS DIRECTORY - NOT HE MSYS 2 I INSTALLED LATER). I chose "MSYS Makefiles" (NOT "MinGW Makefiles"!) with default native compilers. The oce-win-bundle is within oce folder. "current generator: Msys makefiles". All selections cheked as from the documentation. Configuration and building is complete. Then i open msys2 as admin, cd into the Build directory type 'make' and this is what i get

Comment: @BenjaminBihler
User1@User1-PC MSYS ~/Desktop/OpenCascade project/oce/BUILD
# make
Scanning dependencies of target freetype
[  0%] Building C object oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/src/autofit/autofit.c.obj
make[2]: *** [oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/build.make:83: oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/src/autofit/autofit.c.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2540: oce-win-bundle/libs/freetype/CMakeFiles/freetype.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2

Comment: Hmmm, is this the complete error message? Somehow it doesn't tell at all what error has occurred. From your description the only obvious difference I see is that I have never manually set `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`. It is automatically detected by CMake to be `.../mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe` on my computer. But I don't know whether this is the cause for your troubles...?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I do not have a make.exe in Mingw installation location. Although i installed it (like the documentation said). The only make.exe i have is with the msys downloaded files - again from the docs. Although i used msys2 - for the make command.

Comment: Why do you enter the `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` yourself? Is it not correctly detected during configuration? Normally you should not have to enter build tools yourself. CMake will detect them automatically, if they are within your path!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler. When i first configure CMake, it generates a text file in that directory. I manually open the text file and i insert CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCA~1/msys/bin/make.exe, because previsouly there was the record but the location of the make was empty. This make.exe is the one i downloaded from the msys bundle that the documentation said.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I opened a command prompt and typed make and it is not recognized. So make is not in my PATH. But i downloaded msys2 as you said and i installed make there. So even though msys2 recognizes make, command prompt does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219188/discussion-between-benjamin-bihler-and-user1584421).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I built OpenCascade 7.4.0 (static+shared) from http://www.opencascade.com/content/latest-release under MSYS2 using Ninja:

```
INSTALLPREFIX=/usr/local
mkdir -p build_static build_shared &&
 cmake.exe -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX/share/opencascade -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_LIBRARY_TYPE:STRING=Static -DUSE_VTK:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_RAPIDJSON:BOOL=ON -DUSE_FREEIMAGE:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_FFMPEG:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_D3D:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_RELEASE_DISABLE_EXCEPTIONS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_USE_PCH:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_SAMPLES_QT:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_static &&
 cmake.exe -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX/share/opencascade -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_LIBRARY_TYPE:STRING=Shared -DUSE_VTK:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_RAPIDJSON:BOOL=ON -DUSE_FREEIMAGE:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_FFMPEG:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_D3D:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_RELEASE_DISABLE_EXCEPTIONS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_USE_PCH:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_SAMPLES_QT:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_shared &&
 sed -i.bak -e "s/LINK_LIBRARIES *= *[^ ]*libTKTopAlgo\.dll\.a.*-lfreetype.*libTKernel\.dll\.a.*$/& -Wl,--as-needed -lz -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lpng -lbrotlidec/" build_shared/build.ninja &&
 ninja -Cbuild_static install/strip &&
 ninja -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
 echo Success
```